# VisualStudion 2012: Post build Events

Tags: visual-studio-2012, post-build-event, project-properties

In my project I have got following post-build Event:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)Data" "$(ProjectDir)Data" /Y /I
```

After the run has ended the program copies the files. But if in TargetDir/Data is a complete NEW file, this event does not copy the new file to ProjectDir/Data.

but I would like to have this new files copied to TargetDir/Data. How do I achieve this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Data" sounds like a directory, not a file.  You'll have to create it first.  You also appear to have reversed the arguments.  Fix:

```
  if not exist "$(TargetDir)Data" mkdir "$(TargetDir)Data".
  xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Data\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Data" /Y /I /D
```

If you in fact meant to copy *back* to the project directory, very unusual, then just swap TargetDir and ProjectDir in the above snippet.

Comment: the directory is already there... but the hint with the "\*.*" was the key! Thank you very much!                                            
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Data\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Data" /Y /I